# the ws.run_forever() gives me the same values for dema_100 unlike the websocket values that keep changing in real time. dema value different api

Tags: python, loops, websocket, binance

`ws.run_forever()` gives me the same values for dema_100 unlike the websocket values that keep changing in real time. dema value different api

```py
def on_open(ws):
    print('open connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('close connection')

def on_message(ws,message):
    print('recieved message')
    json_message = json.loads(message )
    pprint.pprint(json_message)
    candle = json_message['k']

    is_candle_close = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']   
    if is_candle_close:
        print('candle closed at { }'.format(close))

    result_dema_100 = response_dema_100.json()
    print(result_dema_100)
        
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)

ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: Where did `response_dema_100` come from?  You haven't shown us any of the relevant code.

Comment: from a different api (taapi). this side not letting me post the whole code. so my data is from a binance webstream and the dema is aleady calculated by the taapi database. when i run the code if get a loop of the data from the datastream but the dema_100 is executed only once. so while the data is updating in real time from the webstream the dema_100 data does not because the fucntion only executes it once. so the point is, every time the data loops i want the dema_100 to be executed again so that i get updated data.

Comment: So what's keeping you from calling this function that retrieves the dema_100 data, every time you want to print it out?